Serial communcation misses characters when reading (MTTY exemple confuses me)
I've been trying to establish a communication with an Arduino Nano (a cheap Chinese copy actually).
The board sends 3 characters every seconds, I only get the last 2 characters
I found this documentation that refers to the MTTY sample. I went ahead and found it to take it as an exemple.
I'm intersted in understanding how the reading part is done (in READSTAT.C)
This part confuses me :
    while ( !fThreadDone ) {

        //
        // If no reading is allowed, then set flag to
        // make it look like a read is already outstanding.
        //
        if (NOREADING( TTYInfo ))
            fWaitingOnRead = TRUE;
        
        //
        // if no read is outstanding, then issue another one
        //
        if (!fWaitingOnRead) {
            if (!ReadFile(COMDEV(TTYInfo), lpBuf, AMOUNT_TO_READ, &dwRead, &osReader)) {
                if (GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING)   // read not delayed?
                    ErrorInComm("ReadFile in ReaderAndStatusProc");

                fWaitingOnRead = TRUE;
            }
            else {    // read completed immediately
                if ((dwRead != MAX_READ_BUFFER) && SHOWTIMEOUTS(TTYInfo))
                    UpdateStatus("Read timed out immediately.\r\n");

                if (dwRead)
                    OutputABuffer(hTTY, lpBuf, dwRead);
            }
        }

        //
        // If status flags have changed, then reset comm mask.
        // This will cause a pending WaitCommEvent to complete
        // and the resultant event flag will be NULL.
        //
        if (dwStoredFlags != EVENTFLAGS(TTYInfo)) {
            dwStoredFlags = EVENTFLAGS(TTYInfo);
            if (!SetCommMask(COMDEV(TTYInfo), dwStoredFlags))
                ErrorReporter("SetCommMask");
        }

        //
        // If event checks are not allowed, then make it look
        // like an event check operation is outstanding
        //
        if (NOEVENTS(TTYInfo))
            fWaitingOnStat = TRUE;
        //
        // if no status check is outstanding, then issue another one
        //
        if (!fWaitingOnStat) {
            if (NOEVENTS(TTYInfo))
                fWaitingOnStat = TRUE;
            else {
                if (!WaitCommEvent(COMDEV(TTYInfo), &dwCommEvent, &osStatus)) {
                    if (GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING)   // Wait not delayed?
                        ErrorReporter("WaitCommEvent");
                    else
                        fWaitingOnStat = TRUE;
                }
                else
                    // WaitCommEvent returned immediately
                    ReportStatusEvent(dwCommEvent);
            }
        }

        //
        // wait for pending operations to complete
        //
        if ( fWaitingOnStat && fWaitingOnRead ) {
            dwRes = WaitForMultipleObjects(NUM_READSTAT_HANDLES, hArray, FALSE, STATUS_CHECK_TIMEOUT);
            switch(dwRes)
            {
                //
                // read completed
                //
                case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                    if (!GetOverlappedResult(COMDEV(TTYInfo), &osReader, &dwRead, FALSE)) {
                        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED)
                            UpdateStatus("Read aborted\r\n");
                        else
                            ErrorInComm("GetOverlappedResult (in Reader)");
                    }
                    else {      // read completed successfully
                        if ((dwRead != MAX_READ_BUFFER) && SHOWTIMEOUTS(TTYInfo))
                            UpdateStatus("Read timed out overlapped.\r\n");

                        if (dwRead)
                            OutputABuffer(hTTY, lpBuf, dwRead);
                    }

                    fWaitingOnRead = FALSE;
                    break;

                //
                // status completed
                //
                case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1: 
                    if (!GetOverlappedResult(COMDEV(TTYInfo), &osStatus, &dwOvRes, FALSE)) {
                        if (GetLastError() == ERROR_OPERATION_ABORTED)
                            UpdateStatus("WaitCommEvent aborted\r\n");
                        else
                            ErrorInComm("GetOverlappedResult (in Reader)");
                    }
                    else       // status check completed successfully
                        ReportStatusEvent(dwCommEvent);

                    fWaitingOnStat = FALSE;
                    break;

                //
                // status message event
                //
                case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 2:
                    StatusMessage();
                    break;

                //
                // thread exit event
                //
                case WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 3:
                    fThreadDone = TRUE;
                    break;

                case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
                    //
                    // timeouts are not reported because they happen too often
                    // OutputDebugString("Timeout in Reader & Status checking\n\r");
                    //

                    //
                    // if status checks are not allowed, then don't issue the
                    // modem status check nor the com stat check
                    //
                    if (!NOSTATUS(TTYInfo)) {
                        CheckModemStatus(FALSE);    // take this opportunity to do
                        CheckComStat(FALSE);        //   a modem status check and
                                                    //   a comm status check
                    }

                    break;                       

                default:
                    ErrorReporter("WaitForMultipleObjects(Reader & Status handles)");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }


I think this code is likely to call ReadFile without calling WaitCommEvent, is it correct to proceed this way ? Also I always tried to :

Call WaitCommEvent
Call ReadFile
Call WaitForSingleObject
Call GetOverlappedResult
Recall ReadFile to actually get the datas but it doesn't seem to be necessary

I tryied using this exemple without call WaitCommEvent and it works a little bit, the read operations always miss the first character.
I open the port with GENERIC_WRITE, GENERIC_READ, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED and I appropriately call SetCommMask with the EV_RXCHAR flag.
DWORD WINAPI read(LPVOID param) {
    CUSTOM_DATA* params = (CUSTOM_DATA*)param;
    HANDLE hComm = params->hComm;
    OVERLAPPED ov = { 0 };
    bool waitingOnStat = FALSE;
    int i = 1;
    while (1) {
        char* buffer = (char*)malloc(100 * sizeof(char));
        ZeroMemory(buffer, 100);
        DWORD bufferSize = 100;
        DWORD nbRead;
        DWORD evtMask;
        DWORD res;
        if (!waitingOnStat) {
            ZeroMemory(&ov, sizeof(OVERLAPPED));
            ov.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);

            if (!ReadFile(hComm, buffer, bufferSize, &nbRead, &ov)) {
                if (GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING) {
                    printf("ERROR_IO NOT PENDING\n");
                }
                waitingOnStat = true;
            }
            else {
                std::cout.write(buffer, nbRead) << std::endl;
                waitingOnStat = FALSE;
            }
        }

        if (waitingOnStat) {
            printf("Waiting");
            DWORD res = WaitForSingleObject(ov.hEvent, INFINITE);
            switch (res) {
            case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                waitingOnStat = FALSE;
                DWORD nbBytesTransfered;
                if (!GetOverlappedResult(hComm, &ov, &nbBytesTransfered, TRUE)) {
                        printf("error reading %d\n", GetLastError());
                } else {
                    std::cout.write(buffer, nbRead);
                }
                break;
            default:
                printf("waiting read error %d\n", GetLastError());
                break;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
}

Why is ReadFile constantly returning true ?
Do I need to call WaitCommEvent

Aside: The infinite loop has a memory leak.

Aside: You have a bit of C++ mixed in there at those std::cout.write() calls. They can be replaced with fwrite() calls to keep it C. Also, one of them writes an additional newline and the other one doesn't.

If ReadFile is "constantly returning true", is nbRead ever getting set to 0?

Have you called SetCommTimeouts?

Hello, I have calle the SetCommTimeouts function with both ReadIntervalTimeout = 4294967295 ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 4294967294 ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 4294967295 I did so because  when I connect the arduino IDE to the board and then start a program that calls GetCommTimeouts this is what I get.
I also tried the following because someone on the internet said that it made no sense to have timeouts on the read operation when using OVERLAPPED IO 
ReadIntervalTimeout = 0 ReadTotalTimeoutConstant  = 0 ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0.
I'll see what nbRead contains, thanks

Setting ReadIntervalTimeout = 4294967295 ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 4294967294 ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 4294967295 should cause the read to complete as soon as there is at least one byte in the buffer (maybe immediately). Setting ReadIntervalTimeout = 0 ReadTotalTimeoutConstant  = 0 ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 0 will disable read timeouts, but then it would make sense to at least specify a non-infinite timeout when waiting for events, otherwise it could get stuck forever.

In fact if I put 0 everywhere, then the operation gets stuck on the WaitForSingleObject call, could it have something to do with the way the Arduino sends the data, like maybe the final character is missing (I see the TX led blinking on the board, I tried calling Serial.flush() and it doesn't change anything.
When I set the timeouts to MAXDWORD nbRead is equal to 2 instead of 3.
I'm going to try to put the waitCommEvent back in place to see what happens.

Ok so ReadFile never returning when timeouts are set to 0 seems to be normal behaviour, I don't want that because then I would have to set the waiting parameter and I want the reading to be "in real time" whenever something shows up.

Oh, I would have expected ReadFile to fail with an ERROR_IO_PENDING error if timeouts are disabled and there is nothing in the buffer.

I found a way to make it work, when I call GetOverlappedResult I ignore the nbBytesTransfered when calling std::cout.write (I remember reading -and being told that in asynchronous operations I should ignore this parameter), I put the nbBytesTransfered and now it works

Note that the 4th argument (&nbRead) of the ReadFile call should be NULL in overlapped mode. If ReadFile returns TRUE, use GetOverlappedResult to get the number of bytes read.

… However, according to the docs, the 4th parameter "can not be NULL" for Windows 7!

… Also see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20230215-00/?p=107832 . It is OK for the 4th parameter to be non-NULL as long as race conditions with other threads are avoided. So set it to non-NULL for compatibility with Windows 7, and just ignore the value written there. You have already discovered that ignoring the nbRead value is more reliable!

Thank you a lot for your input @IanAbbott, I wrote a message to finalize this post as I am happy with how it is currently working.
Feel free to add some comment if it can make it any clearer for anyone who may be facing the same issue in the future.
Many thanks !

With @Ian Abbott's help I fiddled with the parameters for COMMTIMEOUTS.
The documentation specifies some behavior such as :

If an application sets ReadIntervalTimeout and ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier to
MAXDWORD and sets ReadTotalTimeoutConstant to a value greater than zero and
less than MAXDWORD, one of the following occurs when the ReadFile function is
called:

If there are any bytes in the input buffer, ReadFile returns immediately with
the bytes in the buffer.
If there are no bytes in the input buffer, ReadFile waits until a byte
arrives and then returns immediately.
If no bytes arrive within the time specified by ReadTotalTimeoutConstant,
ReadFile times out.


The thing is with my code I was :

Calling GetOverlappedResult and then ignoring the nbBytesRead param (because I had read that it should be ignored when using overlapped I/O).

Taking the following measures seem to have corrected my issue :

Use nbBytesTransfered in the when after calling GetOverlappedResult. Although if I set the timeouts to :
timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 4294967295;
timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 4294967294;
timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 4294967295;

ReadFile will return FALSE for the first character that will end up being displayed by the GetOverlappedResult call, then ReadFile will return TRUE and will display the remaining characters (I haven't tested this at high speed).


If I set the timeouts as follow :
timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 10;
timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 100;
timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;

ReadFile doesn't return TRUE and GetOverlappedResult reads all of the characters (I haven't tested this at high speed).
